# Is there any restrictions for video/audio streaming in google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

We are to develop a mobile application in which admin will maintain media in google drive in publicly shared folder.

All users will stream content directly from google drive.

Is there any restrictions on streaming from google drive? Is Google Drive reliable for such use case?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Store and play video in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423694?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1), there seems to be no specific warning about playing videos from Drive, seems that it's been supported from the beginning. Just make sure the videos you streaming are yours or have permission from the owner (for the copyright reasons).